# subset a dataframe based on NOT cumulative sum of rows

Tags: r, sum, subset, rows

I would like to subset a data frame in r based on NOT cumulative sum of rows and more conditions.

For example I have the following data frame:

```
x<-data.frame(x1=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9),x2=c(70,1,6,23,98,21,45,8,6))
```

Now I would like to subset x with 2 conditions:

1. The sum of x2 must be less than 60.
2. x1 must be greater than 2.

So I have tried:

```
subset(x, cumsum(x2)<60 & x1>2)
```

Obviously my code does not work (it returns an empty data frame) because I am trying to use cumsum and the first element of x2 is already greater than 60.

I expect one single data frame which could look like:

```
  x1 x2
3  3  6
4  4 23
6  6 21
8  8  8
```

because the sum of x2 values is less than 60 and the value of x1 is greater than 2.

Since the solution is dynamic, another possible result could be:

```
  x1 x2
7  7 45
8  8  8
9  9  6
```

Or:

```
  x1 x2
3  3  6
```

Once I understand how to implement it, I will restrict the set of possible solutions by adding more conditions.

EDIT for Ronak Shah

Additional column x3, so the data frame x becomes:

```
x<-data.frame(x1=c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9),x2=c(70,1,6,23,98,21,45,8,6),x3=c(13,2,31,45,5,6,7,18,0))
```

The sum of x3 should be less than 20, so x3_tresh should 20.

SOLUTION MODIFIED

```
subset_df_row <- function(x, x1_value, x2_thresh, x3_thresh) {
  #Filter the dataframe based on x1_value
  df1 <- x[x$x1 > x1_value, ]
  #Shuffle rows to get random result
  df1 <- df1[sample(seq_len(nrow(df1))), ]
  #If the first value of x2 is greater than threshold shuffle again
  while(df1$x2[1] >= x2_thresh || df1$x3[1] >= x3_thresh) {
    df1 <- df1[sample(seq_len(nrow(df1))), ]
  }
  #Return the subset
  df1[1 : min((which.max(cumsum(df1$x2) >= x2_thresh) - 1),
              (which.max(cumsum(df1$x3) >= x3_thresh) - 1)), ]
}
```

Comment: If you restrict yourself to a certain size of 'window' (`n`), you could use a rolling sum and extract all subsets of length `n`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We could write a function to subset the dataframe

```
subset_df_row <- function(x, x1_value, x2_thresh) {
    #Filter the dataframe based on x1_value
    df1 <- x[x$x1 > x1_value, ]
    #Shuffle rows to get random result
    df1 <- df1[sample(seq_len(nrow(df1))), ]
    #If the first value of x2 is greater than threshold shuffle again
    while(df1$x2[1] >= x2_thresh) {
      df1 <- df1[sample(seq_len(nrow(df1))), ]
    }
    #Return the subset
    df1[1 : (which.max(cumsum(df1$x2) >= x2_thresh) - 1), ]
}
```

and then pass `x1` and `x2` filter values dynamically

```
subset_df_row(x, 2, 60)
#  x1 x2
#6  6 21
#8  8  8

subset_df_row(x, 3, 160)
#  x1 x2
#8  8  8
#5  5 98
#4  4 23
```

Comment: Great idea! Thanks! Supposing now I have a third column x3 for dataframe x on which I want to apply a not cumulative sum condition like x2 . Should I add a second while loop or can I integrate it both x2 and x3 in the same while loop which shuffle df1? How your last line would change with this other condition on x3. For simplicity, x3<-c(13,2,31,45,5,6,7,18,0) and x3_tresh is 20.

Comment: I modified your solution, correct me if I could improve it more.